# Projecting complex texture on a vault

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I am making an interior of a palace room, which includes digital restoration of the original vault stuccos and paintings. I have made the restored texture for the vault, but I can't find a way to project it properly.
To explain:
I created vaulted ceiling in Rhino, imported to blender and unwrapped. Which looks like this:
[image]

But this does not correspond to what I want, so I have to tweak each part of the vault manually to get this:

[image]

It anyways looks ugly as a UV, very uneffective and hard to match the texture.
Original texture is made following the outlines created by flattening 3D vault in Rhino, with an idea that they should match:

[image]

So the question is:
**Is there any way in Blender to "flatten" that 3D vault UV so that it becomes a rectangle which matches the texture?** So that I don't have to tweak each single vertex or face, as I have to do now.
Something like this (that's just a top view of current vault):

[image]

I would be very grateful for your suggestions!

Comment: Hello, have you tried Project from View?

Comment: @moonboots thank you, I did not know about this option. It's still leaves some tricky UV fixing, but way better than it was!